# Elementwise power function in Python H2OFrame

Tags: python, h2o

I am using H2O with python. I need to do a transformation on a subset of my columns , raise each element to a power of 1.5 . How do I apply an element-wise and/or column-wise power function on a H2OFrame without converting it to a pandas object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `**` to raise each column of an H2O frame

so if your H2O frame is called `frame` you could use the python exponentiation operator  `**` like this: `frame**1.5`

```
import h2o  
h2o.init()  
frame = h2o.create_frame()  
frame**1.5
```